# Why doesn't this For loop work in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

I was trying to get the canvas to display the `i` in a loop - I want the `i` to be changing just like the counting `t`, from 1-9 non-stop. I just couldn't figure out what's wrong. The javascript looks like this:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||  
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||  
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||  
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||  
    function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)}; 
})(); 

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvasId"),
    c = cvs.getContext("2d"),
    t = 0;

window.onload=function loop(){
    window.requestAnimFrame(loop);
    t++;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        c.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
        c.font = "bold 90px Arial";
        c.fillText(i + " " + t, 100, 200);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/luxiyalu/9UZU5/

This is part of a mini game and I've been stuck in here for 2 days; if anyone could tell me what's wrong with it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're iterating i from 0 to 9 in your drawing function, there is no time left between two drawings and the user can only see the last iteration value, that is 9.

I'm not sure of what you really want to achieve but it looks like you want this :

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvasId"),
    c = cvs.getContext("2d"),
    t = 0,
    i = 0;

window.onload = function loop(){
    window.requestAnimFrame(loop);
    i++;
    if (i==10) {
      i = 0;
      t++;
    }

    c.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
    c.font = "bold 90px Arial";
    c.fillText(i + " " + t, 100, 200);

};
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Bv9hT/)

Comment: But if it was because of too little time, why doesn't the number even flicker a bit when I tell `i` to loop from 0 to 999 and the count of `t` slows down remarkably? At least digit changing from 9 to 999 should cause noticeable flicker?

Comment: Most browsers don't redraw the screen until the script ends. This is an important and very useful optimization, and it prevents the canvas from flickering when you draw scenes (i.e. you draw the background and then the foreground).